# Работа с заказчиком

Tags: работа, заказчик

Опишите свою методику работы с заказчиком. Как договариваетесь, какие приемы используете?

А то порой случается так, что проект начался, оговорили детали, но потом постоянно происходят правки, что мешает работе. По мне так это косяк переговоров, ибо можно описать либо ТЗ, либо пользовательскую историю, которую утверждаешь, начинаешь делать версию 1.0 и если и будут правки, то совсем мизерные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На бумагах договариваемся! Загуглить вопрос - *Физическое лицо оказывает услугу физическому лицу* или *Физическое лицо оказывает услугу юридическому лицу*

Нет бумажки, нет стабильности в исполнении, ибо сожрут мозг запросами типа сделайте кнопочку темнее, буковку жирнее и т.д.

Составить ТЗ, ТЗ включить в договор как факт объема выполняемых работ. Любые нововведения после даты заключения договора + pay cash

Comment: P.S. Полезно иметь в знакомых человека с Юр. образованием! И такого который не спал на парах)

Comment: Спасибо, ценные мысли. Что-то еще добавите?

Comment: как же жизненно про "сделайте кнопочку темнее, буковку жирне" xD

Comment: Сквозь это мгого кто прошел)))

Comment: Да да...но это печалька:)